# How to do custom UINavigationBar transitions as seen in the Foursquare iOS app?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, transition, custom-transition

Does anyone know how to customize the default UINavigationBar transition animation like they did for the new foursquare app? The nav bar from first view controller slides away with the view controller instead of the default fade in effect. The nav bar in the second view controller also appears to be transparent.

Here's a screen shot mid transition:

[image]